# iOS Status Bar randomly appears

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

I have a ViewController with a hidden status bar.

On the `viewWillAppear` I used this:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]setStatusBarHidden:YES]
```

My problem is that after a while the status bar just appears. I cant find the reason for this.

Thanks

Comment: if  you tag xcode and statusbar, no one will go to read your question, your tags must include ios and then these NSViewController, iphone, cocoatouch etc

Comment: Do you ever leave the view and come back to it? Does the app ever get sent to the background before this happens?